# Add some space around the headline in a beamer slide

Tags: beamer, header-footer

How can I customise the headline of my slides in order to have some white space above and below the title of the frame?

I guess I should change the template with the following instruction: `\setbeamertemplate{headline}`

but how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your description, it's not clear (at least to me) which template you need to modify; `headline` or `frametile`. Anyways, you can use `\addtobeamertemplate` to add the spacing before (using the first argument) and after (using the second argument) the `headline` or `frametitle` template; a little example (of course, instead of `1cm` you can use the desired length):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{1cm}}{\vspace*{1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the new requirement made in a comment, a redefinition of the `frametitle` template (as defined in `beamerouterthemeshadow,sty` since the theme used is `Warsaw`) is needed:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip.50ex% NEW: original \vskip-.75ex
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \insertframetitle%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \strut\par%
          \else
            \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par\vskip2ex}% NEW: added \vskip2ex
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{1cm}}{\vspace*{1cm}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame Title}
\framesubtitle{Test Frame Subtitle}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The lines that were changed are signaled in the code with `% NEW`; there you can adjust the lengths according to your needs.

Comment: thks so much...exactly what I needed!just another quick question: I'd also like to have some space in the headline around the word (e.g. Test Frame in your slide) so that the size of font is the same but the height of the headline is bigger...how can I do that?

Comment: @Matteo this probably requires a redefinition of the template itself; which theme are you using?

Comment: `\usetheme{Warsaw}`, since I'm kind of a newbie in the beamer package, could you point me out some useful links on the redefinition of templates?

Comment: @Matteo I updated my answer with the needed redefinition; regarding your question, I am not aware of a document explaining the redefinition of templates (the `beamer` documentation contains some explanations, but at a basic level); for more sophisticated changes you need to look at the original code of the templates and made the necessary changes.

Comment: you helped me a lot, thanks... I'll check and let you know if I have doubts... ;)